# how to use eager loading without string for related entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, iqueryable, eager-loading

I would like to use eager loading for load related entities and I see [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx):

In this example I can see that there are two ways to get the related entities:

```
var princesses1 = context.Princesses
                          .Include(p => p.Unicorns)
                          .ToList();


var princesses1 = context.Princesses
                          .Include("Unicorns")
                          .ToList();
```

The first way is to use the lambda expression (I think that correct name is that, if not, correct me), and the second way is to use a string with the name of the related entity.

In my case, I can use the second, because in the firt way, when I can't get the property of the related entity in the lambda expression. I use this code:

```
IQueryable<Customers> myQuery;
myQuery = myContext.Customers.Include("Orders");
```

But if I try to use the second way:

```
IQueryable<Customers> myQuery;
myQuery = myContext.Customers.Include(c=>c.?????);
```

I can't select the Orders property.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the top of your file:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

This includes a reference to a DbExtensions class which provides the include extension method.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `System.Data.Entity` in order to be able to use lambda expression in `Include` method:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: Yes, thaks, I use to include this, but in this class not. Thanks.